# Unable to get user profile data from API

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

I an trying to get the user data from the API and display in the UI using flutter http package. After login in, the API returned 200 OK response. When I tried navigating back to the user profile page to get the logged in user from the API i got a 401 unauthorized access response from the API even after putting the authorization bearer token (gotten from the the login) in the http header it keeps returning 401 response. After the error continued I added a refresh token to the api but the get user keep throwing 401 response.

The Api login service

```
     static Future loginUser(User user) async {
    // Try low level Http_Client
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(
      Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/login'),
    );
    request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.add(
      utf8.encode(
        jsonEncode({
          "userName": user.userName,
          "userEmail": user.userEmail,
          "password": user.password,
        }),
      ),
    );

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String message = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(message);
    httpClient.close();

    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Response: $jsonResponse');
      final _token = jsonResponse['Token'];
      final _expiration = jsonResponse['Expires'];
      await AppStorage.writeKey('token', _token);
      print('Token Expiration: $_expiration');
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonResponse));
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401 || response.statusCode == 403) {
      print('Error Msg: $jsonResponse');
      _refreshToken();
    } else {
      print("Failed Response : $jsonResponse");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The api to get user

```
  static Future getUser() async {
    String? token = await AppStorage.getKey('token');
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.putUrl(
      Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/profile'),
    );
    request.headers.set('Authentication', 'Bearer $token');
    request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var response = await request.close();
    var message = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

    if (message.isEmpty) {
      print('Message Is Empty');
      return;
    } else {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(message);
      print('Message: $message');
      httpClient.close();
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        print('Response: $jsonResponse');
        return User.fromJson(jsonResponse);
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401 || response.statusCode == 403) {
        // If response returns 401 refresh token
        print('Error Msg: $jsonResponse');
        _refreshToken();
      } else {
        print("Failed Response : $jsonResponse");
      }
    }
  }
```

The refresh token api service

```
 static Future<dynamic> _refreshToken() async {
    print('Refreshing Token ...');
    String? token = await AppStorage.getKey('token');
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(
      Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/refresh'),
    );
    request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.headers.set('Authentication', 'Bearer $token');

    var response = await request.close();
    var message = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(message);
    httpClient.close();
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Response: $jsonResponse');

      // Get new token from the response
      final _newToken = jsonResponse['Token'];
      final _expiration = jsonResponse['Expires'];

      // Store the new token
      await AppStorage.writeKey('token', _newToken);
      print('Token Expiration: $_expiration');

      // Retry Get user token
      getUser();
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401 || response.statusCode == 403) {
      // If response returns 401 log the user out
      print('Error Msg: $jsonResponse');
      _logUserOut();
    } else {
      print("Failed Response : $jsonResponse");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the result of print('Response: $jsonResponse') in getUser()

Comment: Run these requests from postman, to find out if the problem is with your code or backend.

Comment: @Naj The response is 401 unauthorized access

Comment: @SalarArabpour After running the request on postman it returns a 401 response

Comment: If you use the exact same token you received from server to authenticate and still getting 401 response, then the problem is from backend.

Comment: Yes, just as @SalarArabpour has said, your issue is from the backend.

Comment: @SalarArabpour can i provide the api url endpoint so you can help me know what's going on?